# Bootstrap Pull Right Block Level

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
  <div class="add-repeat">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right" id="plus"></span>
    <a href="" class="select">ADD PROGRAM</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get this to look like this:

[image]

So esentially I want to pull the glyph right.  I attempted to use the pull-right class but it simply floats the element right.  I want two block level elements with the first pulled to the right.  How can I do this using bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Spans are inline elements so just swap the position of your `a` and `span` tags to this,

```
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="add-repeat">
        <a href="" class="select">ADD PROGRAM</a>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id="plus"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/bVxpRz)